# Using a larger chessboard for ROS stereo calibration?

Tags: calibration, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been trying to calibrate (using **chessboard pattern**) a pair of stereo cameras using the ROS [camera_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration) tool.

However, when I move the stereo cameras far apart (eg:- baseline > 30-40 cm ),
I cannot get the "Size" bar to be filled completely green (please see the GUI images on the above link) even after placing the chessboard calibration pattern very close to the stereo camera.

I am currently using a simple **A4 size** printed paper (stuck on a rigid surface) for calibration.

**My question**: Has anyone used a larger calibration pattern (A3 , A2 , A1 ,A0 size ?) and got better calibration results ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287779/using-a-larger-chessboard-for-ros-stereo-calibration-?/) by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. I've used large (roughly 1m) chessboard patterns for calibration on the PR2 with good results. (see http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrating%20the%20PR2 for pictures)

Keep in mind that if you change the chessboard size or number of squares, you'll also need to change the matching parameters to the calibrator node.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-06**:
Hi, thanks a lot  for confirming and the reminder, I will try it out and soon..Not sure if this can work out for different setups of stereo cameras (I would like to place them as far apart, probably inclined towards each other to increase common field of view and then try to get a good calibration)